# How can I change the state not using button in flutter and problem with flutter sensor

Tags: flutter, dart, android-sensors

Can I ask more? if I want to create an application like heads up what sensor I need to use Gyroscope right.

I need to use a sensor in this code so what I going to add to this code. please help me to solve this problem I'm a Newbie of flutter So I need to use a ternary operator?

flutter can set state inside the Container or padding or anything?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sensors/sensors.dart';

class GameGuessWord extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GameGuessWordState createState() => _GameGuessWordState();
}

class _GameGuessWordState extends State<GameGuessWord> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[900],
      body: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2 - 60),
            child: Text(
              'FootBall',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8)),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  color: Colors.amber[700],
                ),
                child: Text(
                  '60',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This one is an output of this page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EDse.png)

Comment: It's a bit hard understanding your question. Which state do you want to change in this case (the color, the text, etc)? And what issue you ran into when using `setState` to update the state?

Comment: Sorry, I mean when the x y z in the gyroscope is changing to the point that I want so the text and background colour need to change right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very interesting idea for a project. I can give out some clues on how you can implement it.

First, with the [sensor](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors) package, you can listen to the orientation of the phone through the 3 `BroadcastStream`: `accelerometerEvents`, `userAccelerometerEvents`, and `gyroscopeEvents`. With this in mind, we can listen to the changes (particularly the `x`, `y` and `z` values) in the `initState()`, then manipulate the UI based on them.

To demonstrate better, I have here a full working example of just using `accelerometer` values to change the background of the app by first setting the orientation to `Landscape` (for simple demonstration), then listen to the `z` value. You can manipulate the text and other values as well to create the Heads Up! game of your own! Here are the codes:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sensors/sensors.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: GameGuessWord(),
    );
  }
}

class GameGuessWord extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GameGuessWordState createState() => _GameGuessWordState();
}

class _GameGuessWordState extends State<GameGuessWord> {
  Color _backgroundColor = Colors.indigo;

  /// Upright: [-10, 0, 0]
  /// Tilt forward: [0, 0, -10]
  /// Tilt backward: [0, 0, 10]

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        // Manipulate the UI here, something like:
        if (event.z < -6) {
          _backgroundColor = Colors.green;
        } else if (event.z > 6) {
          _backgroundColor = Colors.red;
        } else {
          _backgroundColor = Colors.indigo;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: _backgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2 - 60),
            child: Text(
              'FootBall',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8)),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  color: Colors.amber[700],
                ),
                child: Text(
                  '60',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see, Thanks for the information :D. Now I can develop it furthermore.

Comment: Now I develop it already if you have any suggestion or advise me pls give the feed back in my git hub
https://github.com/china555/ITCS424_Wireless-and-Mobile-Computing/tree/main/Project